# Access to method signature variables in annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, aop

How is it possible to access variables from method signature?

In spring security there is the @PreAuthorize annotation that can make use of **hasPermission** and access variables passed to the method with **#locationDTO**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#locationDTO.parent, 'Location', 'LOCATION_CREATE') ")
public ResponseEntity createLocation(@RequestBody Location locationDTO) {
     .....
}
```

I would like to create a custom annotation that has access to the variables in the same way - how is that possible?

Comment: What are you looking for?  @MyNewAnnotation(abc = #locationDTO.parent) or @MyNewAnnotation("myNewFunction(#locationDTO.parent)")

Comment: I am looking for @MyNewAnnotation(permission = "SOMETHING", target = "locationDTO.parent")

Comment: Does my answer about [how to evaluate SpEL (Spring Expression Language)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53825701/1082681) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how:

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();
ParameterNameDiscoverer parameterNameDiscoverer = new 
DefaultSecurityParameterNameDiscoverer();
String[] parameterNames = parameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(methodSignature.getMethod());
```

returns the list of parameter names, which can be access then.